# Why is it unwise to use a Drain King to unclog a toilet?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, drain, clog

On its website, Consumer Reports has posted a [review and comparison of drain-cleaning products (PDF)](https://www.consumerreports.org/content/dam/cro/news_articles/home_garden/Consumer_Reports_Drain_Cleaners_11-06.pdf).  The article is about ten years old, but it's free even for non-subscribers.

Out of all the products they tested, the Drain King VIP1 kit is one of their favorites.  They say that it's worth keeping the kit on hand.  It's very powerful.  It uses water pressure (from an indoor or outdoor faucet) to clear drain clogs.

The product is [not perfect](http://geekhunter.blogspot.com/2008/02/drain-king-is-no-king.html), but is still useful. (The manufacturer [warns](https://gtwaterproducts.com/index.php/drain-king-2/): "Drain King should be inserted past any potential areas where water might vent out. If not possible, simply close or plug potential vents.")

Where I live, one of the toilets is clogged.

The manufacturer of the Drain King kit [writes](https://gtwaterproducts.com/index.php/drain-king-2/): "We do not recommend using a Drain King to unclog a toilet". Why not?

Comment: Just a guess, but you have the potential to blow out the wax seal under the toilet which will make it leak until the toilet is removed and reset with a new wax ring.

Answer (score 2):

Using water pressure to clean a drain can provide great results and disasters. I have seen where all the poop in the line was pushed back into another bath that only had a sgower, by the time the owner noticed the smell the bath & bedroom floors were covered in waste.